# Best approach for linking diverse entity types in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, orm

**Short version** for the hasty:

There's various tables/entities in my domain model which have the same field (a UUID). There is a table where I need to link rows/instances of such entities to other JPA-managed entities. In other words, the instance of the field in that link table won't be known up-front. The two approaches I can think of are:

- Use an abstract entity and a TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy, or
- use an `@MappedSuperClass` store the class name of the instance in the link table as well, or something similar that lets me define logic for getting the actual instance from the right table.

Both have advantages and disadvantages in terms of complexity and performance. Which do you believe to be best, is there maybe a third option, or have you tried something like this in the past and would advice/strongly warn against?

**Long version** in case you want more background:

I have a database/object model wherein many types have a common field: a universally unique identifier (UUID). The reason for this is that instances of these types can be subject to changes. The changes follow the command model and their data can be encapsulated and itself persisted. Let's call such a change a "mutation". It must be possible to find out which mutations exist in the database for any given entity, and vice-versa, on which entity a stored mutation operates.

Take the following entities with UUIDs as an (extremely simplified) example:
[image: mutable entities]

To store the "mutations", we use a table/entity called `MutationHolder`. To link a mutation to its target entity, there's a `MutationEntityLink`. The only reason this data isn't directly on the `MutationHolder` is because there can be direct or indirect links, but that's of little importance here so I left it out:
[image: mutation entities]

The question comes down to how I can model the `entity` field in `MutationEntityLink`. There are two approaches I can think of.

The first is to make an abstract `@Entity` annotated class with the UUID field. `Customer`, `Contract` and `Address` would extend it. So it is a TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy. I assume that I could use this as a type for the `entity` field, although I'm not certain. However, I fear this might have a serious performance penalty since JPA would need to query many tables to find the actual instance.

The second is to simply use `@MappedSuperClass` and just store the UUID for an entity in the `entity` field of `MutationEntityLink`. In order to get the actual entity with that UUID, I'd have to solve it programmatically. Adding an additional column with the class name of the entity, or something else that allows me to identify it or paste it in a JPQL query would do. This requires more work but seems more efficient. I'm not averse to coding some utility classes or doing some reflection/custom annotation work if needed.

My question is which of these approaches seems best? Alternatively, you might have a better suggestion, or notice I'm missing something; for example, maybe there's a way to add a type column even with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance to point JPA to the right table? Perhaps you've tried something like this and want to warn me about numerous issues that would arise.

Some additional info:

- We create the database schema, so we can add whatever we want.
- A single table inheritance strategy isn't an option. The tables must remain distinct. For the same reason, joined inheritance doesn't seem a good fit either.
- The JPA provider is Hibernate and using things that are not part of the JPA standard isn't an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the entities don't have anything in common besides having a uuid I'd use the second approach you describe: use `MappedSuperclass`. Making the common superclass an entity would prevent you to use a different inheritance strategy if needed, would require a table for that super entity even if no instances exist and from a business point of view it's just wrong.

The link itself could be implemented in multiple ways, e.g. you could subclass `MutationEntityLink` for each entity to map (e.g. `CustomerMutationEntityLink` etc.) or do as you described it, i.e. only store the uuid as well as some discriminator/type information and resolve programatically (we're using that approach for something similar btw.).

Comment: Good to hear you're actually using that approach. It shows that it's feasible. I think subclassing MutationEntityLink for each mapped entity would be very inconvenient, so a sort of discriminator columns sounds best right now.

Comment: @G_H yes that's the reason for deciding against subclasses.

Comment: I like @Thomas' idea of subclassing a MutationEntityLink for every entity. Since it's a technical class providing the link between mutations and your entities, I would go for single table inheritance. The table would have its discriminator column, and one foreign key column for each entity. The table might not be the most elegant representation of your domain model, but you could get good performance out of it.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete This would result in an extra table AND extra entity class in the model for each entity I want to be able to link to mutations. And the domain model is likely to grow over time. Seeing how each of those subclasses/tables would do exactly the same but for a different type, I'd rather solve it programmatically in a generic manner. In my opinion this is a weakness of strong static typing and I don't think it's worth creating tons of boilerplate just to satisfy Java and some API.

Comment: Also, as an aside... Since I'd query the generic `MutationEntityLink` rather than one of the specific tables for a type (since I might not know the type of entity before querying; I could be searching starting from a mutation) resolving to the specific type would still have to be done by JPA. I'd just move the logic to a different place. Granted, JPA would do it without me having to code it and is probably good at it, but at the cost of all those boilerplate classes that don't really do anything.

Comment: There would be only one extra table withe single table inheritance, though with as many columns as entities. But the added benefit is that you don't have to code special data access code and Hibernate would create simple join statements which would be fast. The boilerplate part would only be the different subclasses for each entity, but Eclipse would pretty much generate them to 98% completeness with the proper abstract methods in the base class.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Ahhhh, you're right. I misinterpreted single table inheritance for a moment there. This seems certainly like a viable option. Then the type resolving of the entity linked to the mutation is done by Hibernate. In fact, the creation of the MutationEntityLink subclass for each mutable entity could be automated if I get creative with, say, an annotation processor and templates. Might be able to avoid someone forgetting to add it when introducing a new entity. Great advice! I'm gonna experiment and see what looks easiest to maintain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@MappedSuperclass` while inheriting associations/methods/properties whereas TABLE_PER_CLASS is generally used when you have entity and sub-entities. If there are entities having an association with the base class in the model, then use TABLE_PER_CLASS since the base class behaves like an entity. Otherwise, since the base class would include properties/attributes and methods which are general to such entities not related to each other, using `@MappedSuperclass` would be a better idea

**Example1:** You need to set alarms for some different activities like "take medicine", "call mom", "go to doctor" etc. The content of the alarm message does not matter, you will need a reminder. So use TABLE_PER_CLASS since alarm message, which is your base class is like an entity here.

**Example2:** Assume the base class AbstractDomainObject enables you to create login ID, loginName, creation/modification date for each object where no entity has an association with the base class, you will need to specify the association for the sake of clearing later, like "Company","University" etc. In this situation, using `@MappedSuperclass` would be better.

Comment: The difference between a mapped superclass and table per class inheritance strategy was already clear to me. The challenge in my situation is that there is in fact a table which needs to reference entities that are implementations of the abstract class, but for the domain model and performance `@MappedSuperClass` makes more sense than TABLE_PER_CLASS, so to use that I'd need to create the look-up logic for the right entity type myself. The question comes down to whether that is feasible (Thomas confirms so) and if there's an existing solution/best practice.